# Styling text using CSS like thicker svg text when stroke is defined

Tags: html, css, svg

When the attribute "stroke" of an svg text is defined, the text looks thicker.

I get the same result in webkit, gecko, and trident.

I am working with a designer using svg, I would like to get the same result that he has designed, but in html/css.

Example:

```
<div>bla - html</div>
<div style="font-weight:bold">bla - html bold</div>
<svg height="30px"><text x="0" y="20">bla - svg</text></svg>
<svg height="30px"><text x="0" y="20" stroke="#000000">bla - svg stroke</text></svg>
```

Result screenshot:

[image]

How can I simulate that in html/css?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if you do not set a `stroke-width` , defaut value is **1**  for 1 pixel:

Try this :

```html
<svg height="30px"><text x="0" y="20"  stroke-width="0" stroke="#000000">bla - svg stroke width 0</text></svg>
<svg height="30px"><text x="0" y="20"   stroke="#000000">bla - svg stroke no width defined</text></svg>
<svg height="30px"><text x="0" y="20"  stroke-width="1" stroke="#000000">bla - svg stroke width 1</text></svg>
<svg height="30px"><text x="0" y="20"  stroke-width="2" stroke="#000000">bla - svg stroke width 2</text></svg>
```

---

## At this time

`text-stroke` is actually avalaible in webkit , using vendor prefix. So is `text-fill`.

<del>In near futur it could be</del> avalaible in other browser too , check it out here : http://caniuse.com/text-stroke

## how to use it in webkit browser :

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001266-_webkit_text_stroke

example

```css
p {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke: red 1px;
}
```

```html
<p style="color:white;font:bold 30px arial">text stroke width 1</p>
```

---

## for now

**To stroke text in CSS**, you need to use multiple text-shadow to increase as much as needed the shadow to turn it into a full strike color .

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xklIi/

*(as bigger is the shadow used for stroke effect, as much it needs to be repeated, redrawn)*

```css
p {
  font-wheight:bold;
  letter-spacing:1px;
  color:white;
}
[data-stroke="1"] {
  text-shadow:
    0 0 1px red,
    0 0 1px red,
    0 0 1px red,
    0 0 1px red,
    0 0 1px red,
    0 0 1px red,
    0 0 1px red,
    0 0 1px red,
    0 0 1px red;
}
[data-stroke="2"] {
  text-shadow:
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red;
}
[data-stroke="2sharp"] {
  text-shadow:
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red,
    0 0 2px red;
}
```

```html
<p data-stroke="1">bla - text stroke width 1</p>
<p data-stroke="2">bla - text stroke width 2</p>
<p data-stroke="2sharp">bla - text stroke sharp width 2</p>
```

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question. Can you just add that you can use "-webkit-text-stroke" on webkit only, instead of many text-shadow, and I will accept your answer.

Comment: @Oli thanks, i added the information about webkit possibilitie for now . have a nice day

Answer (score 3):

SVG text elements have attributes: `stroke-width, stroke, and **fill**` .

Try this:

```
<svg id="mySVG" width="400" stroke="black" fill="red" height="400">
<text x=50 y=50 font-size="50"  >ABCD</text>
<text x=50 y=100 font-size="50" stroke="none"  >ABCD</text>
<text x=50 y=150 font-size="50" fill="red" >ABCD</text>
<text x=50 y=200 font-size="50" fill="none" stroke="green" >ABCD</text>
<text x=50 y=250 font-size="50" fill="red" stroke="green" >ABCD</text>
<text x=50 y=330 font-size="100" fill="red" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" >ABCD</text>
```

Comment: I came across this page trying to figure out why my SVG text was looking too big when stroke was defined.  Setting `stroke-width` to 0 and using `fill` works perfectly for me.  So, while this may technically be an answer to a different question, it certainly helped me out :)